# SQLite Select mix column, I can't do it

Tags: sqlite, select

My code is

```
mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_Name + KEY_Familyname + " as " + KEY_Fullname}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

So it's not do

```
Error: "KEY_Name + KEY_Familyname + " as " + KEY_Fullname" ????
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `||` operator to concatenate strings

```
select KEY_Name || KEY_Familyname as KEY_Fullname
```